# Is there an integral separated locally Noetherian scheme that fails to be Noetherian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is there an integral separated locally Noetherian scheme that fails to be Noetherian?

If separatedness is removed, then an example is given by infinitely many copies of $\mathbf{A}^1$ glued along $\mathbf{A}^1-\{0\}$. (Affine line with $\infty$-ed origin.)

Comment: Remember that the title is *not* where you put the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are examples of integral, separated, locally noetherian schemes which are not noetherian. Here is [one description from MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/34656) in an answer to a very similar question:

> There are smooth counterexamples.  Let $S_0$ be a smooth separated irreducible scheme over a field $k$ with dimension $d > 1$, and $s_0 \in S_0(k)$.  Blow up $s_0$ to get another such scheme $S_1$ with a $\mathbf{P}^{d-1}_k$ over $s_0$.  Blow up a $k$-point $s_1$ over $s_0$ to get $S_2$, and keep going.  Get pairs $(S_n, s_n)$ so that the open complement $U_n$ of $s_n$ in $S_n$ is open in $U_ {n+1}$ and is strictly contained in it.  Glue them together in the evident manner, to get a smooth irreducible $k$-scheme.  It is locally of finite type, but is not quasi-compact (since the $U_n$ are an open cover with no finite subcover). This is separated (either by direct consideration of affine open overlaps, or by using the valuative criterion). - [BCnrd](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3927/bcnrd)